# Error Create Function HSQL

Tags: hsqldb

I have an error creating the following function in HSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getmax ()
   RETURNS INT
   BEGIN ATOMIC
     DECLARE max_event INT;
     SET max_event = SELECT MAX(tabla_id) FROM tabla;
     RETURN max_event;
   END
$$
```

Error:

> 5608=42608 wrong or missing data impact clause in declaration

I have looked at the documentation of HSQL and other pages, I invested a great amount of time and I can not solve it.

I need your help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it.

Here is the answer, in case someone else needs it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getmax ()
   RETURNS INT
    READS SQL DATA
     RETURN (SELECT MAX(tabla_id) FROM tabla)
$$
```